# dump app call stack in “for in” only onetime

Tags: ios, objective-c, callstack

```
- (id)objectAtIndexSafe:(NSUInteger)index
{

    if (index < [self count]) {
        return [self objectAtIndexSafe:index];
    }else {
        TTSafeKitAssert(NO, @"unsafe");
        return nil;
    }
}
```

**TTSafeKitAssert** : send dumped threads info(use PlCashReporter) to sever,but when objectAtIndexSafe called in for in，TTSafeKitAssert will send so many times . How can i just send once in this situation！

Comment: When you call it in a loop, it triggers multiple times.  So don't call it in a loop, or break the loop after it's called.

Comment: I hooked system nsarry objectAtIndex to objectAtIndexSafe, how can i break?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a category:

```
- (id)objectAtIndexSafe:(NSUInteger)index
{

    if (index < [self count]) {
        return [self objectAtIndex:index];
    }else {
        TTSafeKitAssert(NO, @"unsafe");
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ganvinalix Inside your if statement you call objectAtIndexSafe again creating a recursive loop

Comment: NO,I swizzle hooked the  objectAtIndex  to  objectAtIndexSafe, call  objectAtIndexSafe means call origin nsarry objectAtIndex!